# How to select a field based on condition on attribute on dataweave Mule

Tags: xpath, mule, dataweave

Hi have the below xml and I need to select the Id with attribute type = select
I have used `cost center:payload.ns0#Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position.ns0#CostCenter.*ns0#ID[?($.@type == "select")],` but its not working as excepted its giving a id val;ue inside the cost tag,Please help

```
wd:Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position>
            <wd:CostCenter wd:Descriptor="0801009345 AUDIT-N AMER SOFT DRINK/FOODS">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e441a75b6dfb1097d9556f00a3e2a2af</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="select">0801009345</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">0801009345</wd:ID>
            </wd:CostCenter>

        </wd:Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean you are getting ID value with type = "Cost_Center_Reference_ID"?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    a: payload.Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position.CostCenter.*ID[?($.@type == "select")]
}
```

I checked above and it properly gave me value of ID where type is Select.

Sample input -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position >
            <CostCenter Descriptor="0801009345 AUDIT-N AMER SOFT DRINK/FOODS">
                <ID type="WID">e441a75b6dfb1097d9556f00a3e2a2af</ID>
                <ID type="select">0801009347</ID>
                <ID type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">0801009346</ID>
            </CostCenter>

        </Job_Application_Job_Requisition_Position>
```

Output-

```
{
  "a": [
    "0801009347"
  ]
}
```

**Note: In your example input ID value of select and Cost_Center_Reference_ID are same, not sure how do you differentiate to say its coming from cost? Is that the problem?**